# ServiceTracker | Should we release service in addingService method in case of exception?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

I have created a **ServiceTracker** with null **ServiceTrackerCustomizer** and overridden addingService and removedService methods.

Consider this code snippet for addingService method.

```
public T addingService(ServiceReference<T> reference) {
    T service = super.addingService(reference);
    try {
        // some code which may throw exception. 
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Let's not track if exception occurred.
        service = null;
        this.context.ungetService(reference);
    }
    return service;
}
```

So, is it ok to eagerly release the service in case of exception? Or we can just omit it and OSGi framework will take care of releasing the service later?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should unget the service as you show in the question.